# JQuery UI Dialog disappears when an edit button in my gridview is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this asp page that I'm working on and it has a gridview control in it that has edit buttons. I'm able to get the edit button to show the JQuery UI dialog. The problem is that when I click on the button, the dialog opens and then closes really quickly. Here is the markup for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
       BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
       OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
       style="margin-bottom: 0px" >
       <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton Id="btnEditRow" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="EditRecordOpen('editForm');" OnClick="btnEditRow_Click" runat="server" />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="Start Time" 
                      SortExpression="StartTime" >
                      <ItemStyle Width="180px" />
                 </asp:BoundField>
       </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And this is what my javascript looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#editForm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: true,
                title: "Edit Record",
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                }
            });
        });

        function EditRecordOpen(id) {
            $("#" + id).dialog("open");
            return false;
        }

        function EditRecordClose(id) {
            $("#" + id).dialog("close");
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

I read on another StackOverflow question that placing

```
 return false;
```

would stop the behavior but its still disappearing.

There are 3 functions that control the button clicks associated with the dialog as well:

```
private void CloseDialog(string dialogId)
{
      string script = string.Format(@"closeDialog('{0}')", dialogId);
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, script, true);
}

protected void btnSaveRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      CloseDialog("editForm");
}

protected void btnEditRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var editLink = ((LinkButton)sender);
      editRecordPanel.Update();
}
```

I tried using Chrome developer tools as well to see what was happening during the click, but I'm not seeing any errors related to the dialog.

Also, I used the sample from http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html page to set up the dialog

As well, my popup is defined here:

```
<div id="editForm">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="editRecordPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="popupTest" runat="server" Text="Test"></asp:Label>
               <asp:Button ID="btnSaveRecord" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveRecord_Click" />
          </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: Is all that inside UpdatePanel ? - From what I see on second look, after the dialog appears you make postback by calling the code behind. That dialogs can not hold/stop the post back, like the one and only browser dialog that make question. So is normal, you open the dialog, and then is close because of the post back and the page is reloaded.

Comment: So that's why the dialog is only showing up for a second? How can I stop that? Also, I put all of my markup for the popup in the question. I forgot to add that originally.

Comment: Place that `OnClientClick="EditRecordOpen('editForm');return false;"` and then you have your dialog open, but I do not know what you want to do  next

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Next, I need to get the row data so that users can edit it. But I should probably make that another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, @Aristos helped me figure out that I needed to place

```
return false;
```

inside the

```
OnClientClick="EditRecordOpen('editForm'); return false;"
```